# Is bloc pattern mandatory for a professional app?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, bloc

I'm building an app (10 screens+) with Flutter and been wondering if my app's structure were good.

```
root
-- src [contains all app structure] 
---- assets [contains things like images, fonts...)
---- controllers [contains all code logics]
------- screenNameOne
---------- screenNameOneController.dart
---- helpers [contains all helpers functions]
---- models [contains my models]
---- providers [contains my external apps calls like firestore, SharedPrefs..)
---- views [contains "only" UI code] 
------- screenNameOne
---------- widgets [contains widgets that don't relies on Streams]
---------- streams [contains widgets that relies on Streams]
---------- screenNameView.dart
-- main.dart
```

I've seen many examples with bloc pattern but is it a mandatory thing for a "pro" app to be deployed on stores? I'm not a fan of external libraries and I have to admit that I like my "MVC" pattern, but does it seems professionnal to you?

Thanks

Comment: its certainly not mandatory to use BLOC. But for larger apps you would want a state management library. BLOC is one of them, Provider a different... and there is a lot more like redux

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But it may be a stupid question but why are they called "State management libraries" ? I mean, I can manage state directly from my controller with Streams even with "my" architecture. For example, I have in every controllers a "isLoading" Stream, and in my view I check if the isLoading Stream == true, else I'm displaying page content. Is that wrong?

The problem is that I have use a StreamBuilder for every dynamic variables of my controller, else, I can use a FutureBuilder

Comment: Nothing wrong with using streams. Its just a matter of taste. Provider, the only state management lib i know because thats what i use gives you some more options as just using streams. Kind of dependency injection mechanism and more....But your structure looks good from the infos you provided. There will be 1000 approaches because like with react, there is no "single way to do it". Everyone does it slightly different.